# Check if a session exist, if not then a file must be uploaded

Tags: session, laravel-5

I'm trying to create an order system. The user needs to upload a file or fill in a mail form. If the mail form is filled in correctly it's creating a session.

So I need to check if the session exist so not the user must be upload a PDF file.

I would like to use the Laravel validator rules to check this, but i don't know how i can check if the session exists

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Yes, but that is a normal array for rules

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will have to write custom validation rule. You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules)